# Coloring the line

Tags: geometry, coloring

You probably know the [Hadwiger-Nelson problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem), which states:

> What is the minimal number $k$ such that there is a $k$-coloring of the plane such that no two points at distance $1$ have the same color?

This problem is open. There are known upper ($k=7$) and lower ($k=4$) bounds.

My question is: is the same problem for the *line* solved? I can see the obvious bound below given by $2$ and $3$ as a bound above, given by the coloring by intervals of length $\frac{2}{3}$. But is there a $2$-coloring of the line solving the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! For $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, consider a relation $a \sim b \iff a - b \in \mathbb{Z}$ -- that is, two numbers are in the relation if they differ by an integer. This is an equivalence relation, and it's easy to see that its equivalence classes are of the form $[x] = \{ x + k: k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Consider the set of equivalence classes $A = \mathbb{R}/\sim$. Pick a choice function $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ that from each equivalence class picks a representative, i.e. satisfies $x = [f(x)]$: it exists by the axiom of choice. Now we'll construct a coloring, that is, a function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \{0, 1\}$: for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, consider $x = f([a])$. Since $[x] = [a]$, $a = x + k$ for some integer $k$. Put $g(a) = k \mod 2$. I'll leave it for you to show that $g$ is actually the coloring we want.

Comment: no need for the axiom of choice. Here is a complete choice of representatives: $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 4):

A colouring of the line using just two colours would be to colour the intervals $[n,n+1)$, where $n\in \mathbb Z$ alternatively using the two colours. Clearly, no two points of distance $1$ have the same colour.